# C/C++ pointer as base of memory reference?

Tags: gcc, g++, inline-assembly

Can a pointer be used as offset and base of a memory reference with `inline assembly`?

For example:

```
int main(){
 char a[16],b[16];
 asm volatile("\
 movq $123,16(%%rsp,%%rbx,1)"
 :"=m"(*a)::"rbx");
}
```

Could be something like:

```
int main(){
 char a[16],b[16];
 asm volatile("\
 movq $123,(%0,%%rbx,1)"
 :"=m"(*a)::"rbx");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your example.  As written, the contents of rbx are undefined?  Maybe you mean something like this: `for (unsigned long long d = 0; d < sizeof(b); d++)  asm ("movq $123,(%1,%2)" : "=m"(a) :"r"(a), "r"(d));`

Answer (score -1):

One choice is to use one additional register:

```
int main(){
 char a[16],b[16];
 asm volatile("\
 lea %0,%%rcx\n\
 movq $123,(%%rcx,%%rbx,1)"
 :"=m"(*a)::"rbx","rcx");
}
```